# Machine Learning - Map same line of training data to multiple targets

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

Let me start by saying that I am total noob when it comes to Machine Learning, so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

---

I was making a MultinomialNB model following this [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#loading-the-20-newsgroups-dataset). 
And I was wondering if there was a way to map a single line to multiple targets classes.
For example, I have the sentence "Jesus cures cancer" and want it to map to *both* 'sci.med' and 'soc.religion.christian'. 
Is there a way to do that in SciKit? 
**Can I just put the same sentence twice with the different targets, or will that distort the final model?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are wanting to do is called multilabel classification; some scikit-learn classifiers support it, [here's the documentation with more details.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html)

If you put the same sentence twice into a model that is trying to predict one outcome, it will just confuse the model as one training example said it was one class and another said it was a different class and it is only learning to predict one class.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I wanted! Can SciKit's multinomialNB be implemented as multilabel? Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: Did you find more on this? How did it go with your desired result and what did you use as a solution. Your thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, scikit's multinomialNB can be implemented as multilabel.

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

classifier=OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB)
```

You can now use "classifier" to fit your training data.

You can learn more about OneVsRestClassifier [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier)